# Serilog Seq package does not install on .NET Standard 2.0 library project

Tags: .net, serilog, seq, .net-standard-2.0, seq-logging

I created a .NET Standard 2.0 library project using Visual Studio and tried to install Seq as follows.

```
Install-Package -Id Serilog.Sinks.Seq
```

The top line of error says

```
Unable to find package 'Serilog.Sinks.Seq' at source ''.
```

Full detail is in this screenshot.

[image]

Just as a comparison, installing the following Serilog packages on the same project works just fine

```
Install-Package -Id Serilog
Install-Package -Id Serilog.Enrichers.Thread
```

What is happening? Is it a .NET Core/Standard issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the package installs fine into .NET Standard 2.0 class libraries.

The issue here is seems to be where the NuGet client is looking for packages. In the *Package Manager Console* window, try selecting NuGet.org from the package source drop-down.

(The other packages that are succeeding are probably cached on the machine.)

Comment: Setup for NuGet.org seemed to be fine but there was another private source that I disabled. Rebooted the machine. The package installs now. Thank you for the tip.